# MeteorJS, mdg:geolocation, and mongodb 2dsphere queries

Tags: mongodb, meteor, geolocation

I have a meteor app where I'm trying to find nearby people logged into my app. I'm using `mdg:geolocation` to get the coordinates and store them in mongo as `geoJSON`. Due to `Geolocation.latLng()` being reactive, I have to wait until it responds before I can query mongo for nearby people. I'm doing that by using `Tracker.autorun()` and publishing a collection with a geolocation filter.

In the client:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Tracker.autorun(function () {
    var coords = Geolocation.latLng();
    if (coords) {
      Meteor.subscribe("people", coords);
    }
  });
});
```

In the server:

```
Meteor.publish("games", function (c) {
  return People.find({ location:
                      {$near:
                        {$geometry:
                          {type: "Point", coordinates: [c.lng, c.lat] }
                        , $maxDistance: 30}
                      }
                    });
});
```

While this is working, it is not efficient. Every time the browser location changes it cause a new subscription.

I feel like there has to be a better way to do this. I'm fairly new to meteor so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What if I told you that you could use Mongo aggregation? The general idea here is to you'd want the 'nearest-locations' to update automatically with a change in the `'People'` collection thus use publication with an observe. best

Here's the set-up. The first step is to get the aggregation framework package which wraps up some Mongo methods for you. Just `meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate` and you should be in business. This will add an aggregate method to your collections.

An alternative to adding the aggregation framework support is to call directly your mongoDB and access the underlying collection methods, which in this case you need the .aggregate() method. So, use this to connect in the mongoDB :

```
var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db,
    People = db.collection("People");
```

Now you can dive into the aggregation framework and build up your pipeline queries.

The following example demonstrates how to get the aggregation in the publish reactive with observe using [ES6 in Meteor](https://medium.com/@dferber90/es6-in-meteor-5e088c998e4a#.d37h8ltec), exactly like in the `'counts-by-room'` [example](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) in the meteor docs.

With the observe, you will know if a new location has been added, changes or removed. For simplicity, re-run the aggregation each time (except remove) and if the location was previously published then **[`update`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_changed)** the publish, if the location was removed then **[`remove`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_removed)** the location from the publish and then for a new location use **[`added`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_added)** event:

```
Meteor.publish('games', function(c) {
    let initializing = 1, run = (action) => {
        // Define our aggregation pipeline ( aggregate(pipeline) )
        let pipeline = [
            {
                "$geoNear": {
                    "near": { "type": 'Point', "coordinates": [Number(c.lng), Number(c.lat)]},
                    "distanceField": 'distance',
                    "maxDistance": 30,
                    "spherical": true,
                    "sort": -1
                }
            }
        ]
        People.aggregate(pipeline).forEach((location) => {
            // Add each of the results to the subscription.
            this[action]('nearest-locations', location._id, location)
            this.ready()
        })
    }

    // Run the aggregation initially to add some data to your aggregation collection
    run('added')

    // Track any changes on the collection you are going to use for aggregation
    let handle = People.find({}).observeChanges({
        added(id) {
          // observeChanges only returns after the initial `added` callbacks
          // have run. Until then, you don't want to send a lot of
          // `self.changed()` messages - hence tracking the
          // `initializing` state.
          if (initializing && initializing--)
            run('changed')
        },
        removed(id) {
            run('changed')
        },
        changed(id) {
            run('changed')
        },
        error(err) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("Aaaaaaaaah! Grats! You broke it!", err.message)
        }
    })

    // Stop observing the cursor when client unsubs.
    // Stopping a subscription automatically takes
    // care of sending the client any removed messages.
    this.onStop(function () {
        handle.stop();
    })
})
```